# How can I test the effects of CLONE_VM, CLONE_FS, and CLONE_IO in C?

Tags: c, linux, io, exec, clone

I'm trying to understand what these flags do and I've read the descriptions and done some googling but I don't know how to test the difference between the child and parent processes when these flags are set.  What C functions or linux commands can I run to help me see the effects of these flags?

Comment: What are you trying to understand here? `clone()` has very little utility outside of implementations of containers and threading libraries.

Comment: I'm using CLONE and to understand the namespaces etc of processes.  I've been able to test the effects of setting other flags on the child process but I don't know how to see the difference between the parent and the child process when I set these flags.  So for instance when I use CLONE_IO, what is the visible of effect of having the two processes run with the same IO context?  I've tried to use mount() to test CLONE_FS but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly.  I either want to test them in C or spawn a Linux shell and test them from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent example of [`CLONE_FS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) is in my opinion an alternative answer to: "Why does `cd` have to be a shell built-in?"

Usually when you run a process they do only share certain information, most notably open file descriptors but not things like the "current file system".

That means that when `cd` is implemented as a process a call to `chdir()` will:

1. start a new process
2. within *that* process `chdir()` is executed and *that* process changes the directory
3. the process ends and returns control to the parent which has been in the the directory it was all along

   ```
   CLONE_FS (since Linux 2.0)
          If CLONE_FS is set, the caller and the child process share the
          same filesystem information.  This includes the root of the
          filesystem, the current working directory, and the umask.  Any
          call to chroot(2), chdir(2), or umask(2) performed by the
          calling process or the child process also affects the other
          process.
   ```

Now imagine you have `CLONE_FS` set. Pay attention to: "This includes ... the current working directory ...". That means that the call to `chdir()` will not only affect the process that is currently running but also the process(es) in the current namespace.

All of my description is pretty much summarized in the last sentence of the paragraph:

> If CLONE_FS is not set, ... Calls to chroot(2), chdir(2), or umask(2) performed later by one of
> the processes do not affect the other process.

Comment: Also: That's what I call lag :)